# Iphone File Transfer using xmpp

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp

I am trying to implement file transfer using Xmpp. i need to send images from one user to another. i have seen some questions on stack overflow but no one seems to have succesfully implemented using XEP 65. is it even possible to tranfer files using xep 65 on iphone. if not what is the alternative to achieve it. some tutorials would be really grateful
Thnks a lot in advance